# Let method take any data type in c#

Tags: c#, .net, tdd

I have a lot of unit tests that pretty much tests the same behavior. However, data type changes.

I am trying to create a generic method that can take any data type. I tried making my input parameter var but that's not allowed. Also, looked into c# generics but that usually deals with a list.

Comment: Although object work as SLaks said, I'm not sure what your problem with generics is.

Comment: Show us the methods (boil down to their essence) and we can suggest something. As it stands, your question suggests the answer is `void MyMethod<T>(T t) { ... }` but that is too general to be useful.

Comment: Just to emphasize this point: Generics are **NOT** bound to lists. They can be used for any kind of class or method.

Comment: Thanks everyone, also why can I not create a method with var as an input paramter? Something like void MyMethod(var par1) {...}

Comment: Because `var` isn't a data type. It's an instruction to the compiler to _infer_ the data type.

Comment: `var` is only a shortcut; it doesn't mean anything by itself. It's only allowed when the rest of the line makes it obvious what the real type should be. If you type out `Dictionary x = new Dictionary();`, you've just told the compiler twice what `x` is. So typing `var x = new Dictionary();` means exactly the same as if you typed the whole thing out. It's not the same as `var` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could make the parameter an `object`:

```
public void DoSomething(object arg)
{
   //...
```

Or you could do what I prefer and make a generic method:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T arg)
{
    //...
```

The generic approach has two major advantages, and I'll give examples of why they're useful:

1. Even though you don't explicitly specify the type of `arg`, you still have access to it.
2. You can add constraints on the types you want to allow.

Conversely, the `object` approach has some important disadvantages:

1. Since you're treating `arg` as an `object`, you'll only be able to do things you could do with *any* object.
2. If you pass a value type as an `object` parameter, the variable will be [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), which means a performance hit. It's not a huge hit, but if you call `DoSomething` several thousand times in a row, you might start feeling it.

### Generics and Type Constraints

Adding a type constraint to a generic method allows you to restrict the method so that it only accepts certain types. Why is that useful? Because even though you don't know—or care—what specific type you're working with, you now know something about it, and you can use that information.

Consider the following setup:

```
public interface IAnimal 
{ 
    void Move(); 
}
public class Duck : IAnimal
{
    public void Move() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Flying"); 
    }
}
public class Fish : IAnimal
{
    public void Move()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Swimming"); 
    }
}
public class Ant : IAnimal
{
    public void Move()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Walking"); 
    }
}
```

Since we have an `IAnimal` interface, we can write generic methods targeting **any** implementation of `IAnimal`:

```
public class Program
{
    static void DoMove<T>(T animal) where T : IAnimal
    {
        animal.Move();
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Duck duck = new Duck(); 
        Fish fish = new Fish();
        Ant ant = new Ant(); 

        DoMove<Duck>(duck);
        DoMove<Fish>(fish);
        DoMove<Ant>(ant);
    }
}
```

Run it: http://rextester.com/GOF1761

When we write the `DoMove` method, we don't care whether its parameter `animal` is a `Duck`, a `Fish`, an `Ant`, or anything else. All we care about is calling `animal.Move()`. Since we used the `where T : IAnimal` constraint, the compiler knows everything we need it to know:

1. The variable `animal` is of type `T`.
2. Whatever `T` is, it implements `IAnimal`.
3. Anything that implements `IAnimal` has a `Move()` method.
4. Therefore, we can safely call `animal.Move()`.

(By the way, yes, we could just write `DoMove` as `static void DoMove(IAnimal animal)`, but that's another discussion.)

### Type Inference (and some of its implications)

Fine, but let's take it a step further. In many cases, you can call generic methods without having to specify their type parameters. This is called [type inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and aside from saving you some typing, it can be useful when doing the same operation on objects of different types.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    IAnimal[] animals = new IAnimal[] 
    {
        new Duck(),
        new Fish(),
        new Ant()
    };

    foreach (IAnimal animal in animals)
    {
        DoMove(animal);
    }
}
```

Run it: http://rextester.com/OVKIA12317

You only have to write the `DoMove<T>` method once, and you can call it on any type of `IAnimal` without having to give a more specific type. The appropriate version of Move will be called each time, because `DoMove<T>` is able to infer which type to use for `T`. When you call `DoMove(duck)`, .NET understands that you really mean `DoMove<Duck>(duck)`, which then calls the `Move` method on the `Duck` class.

Comment: I should mention that I've gotten a lot of use out of this sort of thing in real-world programming, and it's saved me a ton of time. I've found it especially useful with the Entity Framework, though explaining my exact use cases would take a lot more room.

Answer (score 8):

You can take in `object` as a parameter type.  Even better, perhaps, would be to use generics:

```
void MyMethod<T>(T parm) { ... }
```

This way the parameter is actually of the type the user passed in -- it isn't boxed like with `object` and value types.

Comment: Thanks , also why can I not create a method with var as an input paramter? Something like void MyMethod(var par1) {...}

Comment: @social, the C# language designers chose to make it so that **var** is only valid for local variable declarations.  In principle, they could have supported it in other constructs like method parameters, but it would have added no real value and would have made the public APIs of a class (the methods/properties/etc.) less readable.

Comment: @social, actually, come to think about it, they could *not* have supported it for method parameters (input) but they could have supported it for the return type of a method (output).   This is because use of **var** requires that the variable be initialized with the declaration.  Obviously this would be impossible for parameters, since said variable would be initialized at the calling site.

Answer (score 4):

```
void MyTestMethod<T>(T t) { }
```

gets you a generic test method, but I can't imagine any way that could be useful. What do you need to test? How do you know type `T` has those methods? `T` can be *any* type in the above method. The only methods you can call from `t` in the above example are the common methods of `object`.

What you really need to do is identify a *common behaviour* against one or more types which you want to test, and define the syntactical contract of that behaviour through an interface. You can then constrain your generic test method to only accept types which implement that interface.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
} 

void MyTestMethod<T>(T t) where T : IMyInterface
{ 
    t.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't just using IMyInterface instead of T for the type of t just work?

Comment: @Scott: yes good point, I didn't give the best example. I suppose the point of generics would be that you can have multiple constraints - `where T : IMyInterface, ISomeOtherInterface, new()` or whatever

Answer (score 3):

```
public void YourMethod<T>(T parameter)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your parameter type "object" and your method will accept every type as input. Then you can detect its type using GetType(), and even use tools like int.Parse, ToString(), and type casting to convert your input to a specific type and then work with it.

```
    static void whatsmytype(object place)  // Will accept any type
    {
        Type t = place.GetType(); // detects type of "place" object
        if (t.Equals(typeof(string)))
            Console.WriteLine("Type is string.");
        else if (t.Equals(typeof(int)))
            Console.WriteLine("Type is int.");
        else 
            Console.WriteLine("Type is unknown.");
    }
```

Edit: If readability is not really an issue, you could replace the method declaration line with code below, to get a minor speed improvement:

```
        static void whatsmytype<T>(T place)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use dynamic keyword, this will work provided that all of your different types have the same methods that are used by your unit tests, otherwise you will get a run-time exception